# Tested a code snippet from jsforcats.com. Execution speed seems to be slow in firefox. Why?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, firefox, execution

Chrome vs Firefox. Current versions. Tested with add-ons turned off. Refreshed Firefox as well.

```
function measureLoopSpeed() {
  var count = 0
  function addOne() { count = count + 1 }

  // Date.now() returns a big number representing the number of
  // milliseconds that have elapsed since Jan 01 1970
  var now = Date.now()

  // Loop until Date.now() is 1000 milliseconds (1 second) or more into
  // the future from when we started looping. On each loop, call addOne
  while (Date.now() - now < 1000) addOne()

  // Finally it has been >= 1000ms, so let's print out our total count
  console.log(count)
}
undefined

//On Firefox console
measureLoopSpeed()
4227461 debugger eval code:14:11
undefined
measureLoopSpeed()
4103189 debugger eval code:14:11
undefined

//On Chrome console
undefined
measureLoopSpeed()
11193127
undefined
measureLoopSpeed()
11153367
undefined
measureLoopSpeed()
11159575
```

​***The total tasks done in 1 second is not even close to what chrome did in 1 second.

Comment: What is the point of this code? It shows you nothing of substance. Perhaps `Date.now()` is more expensive on FF which only really happens to impact this case. Which isn't realistic, so whatever.

Comment: You could be correct that Date.now() is more expensive on FF. It ran that many calculations which is total count you can see there in 1 second. How many times you can do count + 1  by hand  in 1 second ; )? That's why I think it is significant.

Comment: The problem is that you're not measuring "how much I can do in 1 second" but *specifically* "how many times I can call `Date.now()`, and perform subtraction, and a logical test in 1 second". So, your test doesn't measure "amount of work" generically. It's only valid for this one specific case. This one specific case is wildly unrealistic, so the data obtained is essentially useless.

Comment: https://jsforcats.com/#callbacks

Comment: And why is Date.now() expensive in FF?

Comment: "*here is a program that tests to see how many tasks JavaScript can process in one second.*" I can only say it's wrong. It's not "how many tasks" - it's only *this* one task. Only one particular task is being executed that many times. [Try this](https://jsbin.com/jaxujew/edit?js,console). It took 2ms on my machine. And that's `4227461` tasks that were executed in 1/500th of a second. [This one](https://jsbin.com/qamifoq/edit?js,console) took 20ms and that's still 1/50th of a second. Not all tasks are equal.

Comment: "*And why is Date.now() expensive in FF?*" I don't know *if* it is. I expressed a hypothesis. Just tried to show you that it's not necessarily "the loop" that's slow. Point was that you do more than just the loop. It might also be different loop optimisation between Chrome and Firefox. Maybe Chrome has better optimisation for *this* particular scenario. It's still worthless to try and interpret this because, *again*, the code is unrealistic. Doesn't serve to paint a picture for any real-world usage.

Comment: Did you run your 2 tasks in firefox dev console and chrome dev console both? In firefox I got 1158ms for 2nd task while in chrome console it was 15ms?